# Passing a function with args as a callback in C?

Tags: c, callback

I have the following simplified code and I would like to know if it is possible to pass an argument to the callback function below:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* foo = "hello!!!!";

bool is_not_char(char x)
{
    bool result = false;
    if (x == '!') result = true;
    
    return !result;
}

void sv_chop_left_while(char* input, size_t count, bool (*predicate)(char x))
{
    size_t i = 0;
    while (i < count && predicate(input[i])) {
        printf(">%c< [%d]\n", input[i], i);
        i += 1;
    }
}

int main(void) {
  sv_chop_left_while(foo, strlen(foo), is_not_char);
}
```

So is it possible to do something like:

```
sv_chop_left_while(foo, strlen(foo), is_not_char, '!');
```

Right now, that char used for the comparison is hardcoded. I'm aware that this is possible by completely avoiding the cb mechanics, but this is a POC for these kind of issues.

The output looks like that right now:

```
>h< [0]
>e< [1]
>l< [2]
>l< [3]
>o< [4]
```

***Some references:***

The original projects repo - https://github.com/tsoding/sv/tree/master

My CompilerExplorer link - https://godbolt.org/z/9G8e9sb5M

Comment: Yes it's possible.  Did you try it?

Comment: What sort of possibility do you envision? If you can change the declarations and calls of `is_not_char` and `sv_chop_left_while`, then you can modify the code to pass another argument (or change the type of the argument to include extra information, such as making it a structure). If you cannot change the declarations, the only way the code of `is_not_char` could be written to use additional information is to provide it via some external identifier.

Comment: I don't know how to do it :) I don't know how to move forward from here, when I tried it, it was complaining about unmatched args count etc.

Comment: (Actually, technically, you could make a horrible kludge in which if `is_not_char` were called with some special value, say zero, then it entered a mode in which the next call provided a character to be used in later comparisons, and `is_not_char` used `static` objects to remember its mode and the set character.)

Comment: @mbilyanov Then show us what you tried so we can see what you might have done wrong.

Comment: That function needs to be rewritten as `bool is_not_char(char x) { return x != '!'; }`.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? I'm not sure that a parameterized predicate function brings an advantage. It seems like a better name and a better implementation (as @Lundin suggests) would be best, e.g., `bool is_not_bang(char c) { return c != '!'; }`.

Comment: If you are looking for ways to pass a partially applied function as an argument then I don't think there is a general way to do in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* foo = "hello!!!!";

typedef bool (*predicate_t)(char x, char y);

bool is_not_char(char x, char y)
{
    bool result = false;
    if (x == y) result = true;
    
    return !result;
}

void sv_chop_left_while(char* input, size_t count, predicate_t predicate, char y)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    while (i < count && predicate(input[i], y)) {
        printf(">%c< [%d]\n", input[i], i);
        i += 1;
    }
}

int main(void) {
  sv_chop_left_while(foo, strlen(foo), is_not_char, '!');
}
```

Comment: Or alternatively `typedef bool predicate_t (char x, char y);` ... `predicate_t* predicate`

Comment: Never `typedef` a pointer to something. `C` has `*` since the beginning. If you see `predicate_t` and `predicate_t*` it is clear that one is a pointer...

Comment: `printf(">%c< [%d]\n", input[i], i);` --> `printf(">%c< [%zu]\n", input[i], i);`. `i` is a `size_t` and must use the `%zu` conversion specifier; arguments that are not matched to their conversion specifiers cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Do you say, that declaring a function pointer with a typedef is a bad idea? Sure, typedefing a pointer carelessly is dangerous, but is there any better way to make it clear that a given type is a function pointer?

Comment: @Fylyp: A reason to use a function type for the `typedef` rather than a function pointer is that you cannot define a function as a `typedef` alias, so using a function type gives a way to find some bugs: Consider `typedef int FunctionType(int, int);` in some header. In a source file, we can write `FunctionType foo;` to declare `foo`, and then we can write `int foo(int a, int b) { return a+b; }`, and the compiler would give us an error if the type in the function definition did not match the declaration. So we can connect the `typedef` to the definition…

Comment: … If the `typedef` were `typedef int (*FunctionType)(int, int);`, then we could not declare `FunctionType foo;` to tell the compiler the function definition must match the `typedef` type. Also, note that, when you do this, you can leave the parameter declaration as `predicate_t predicate`, because a declaration of a parameter as a function will be automatically adjusted to be a declaration of a pointer to a function.

Comment: Thank you for this hint! I totally agree with you.

Comment: Does this answer need updating in the light of the discussion between @Fylyp and Eric Postpischil? Thanks.

Comment: No update needed. Thank you.